# Multiple ActiveX Elements of the same Type

Tags: c++, mfc, activex

I have been struggling with ActiveX elements for the past couple of month and am desperate enough to ask for help.

I am working on my Bachelor's project for my local optics and laser department. We work a lot with machinery from Thorlabs. One of these, is a set of Piezo controlled actuators. To use them, I was provided a controller, model number BPC 103, a three Channel Unit, which comes with different architecture than the one and two channel units. To sum it up, one and two channel units are one unit, with different channels. A three channel unit consists of a communication hub, and three one channel units, called cards in the literature.

As I require more than the manual control provided by Thorlabs' own software, I decided to write a custom script, which will control the actuators dependent on an electrical feedback signal. My problem stems from the way you control the actuators.

You start of by creating ActiveX Elements, and designating them with a control type, in this case MGPiezo Control. Then a serial number is added, which is related to the controller you use. Then, a couple of functions are called to start the control, and then you can start moving the actuators.

The problem starts when you try to control multiple elements of the same type, at the same time. For stepper motors this would not be an issue, as you could just move them individually, and end at the correct spot. For piezos, this is not possible, as the second you stop actively controlling them, the voltage drops of and the actuators retract again.
I have recreated this error in both QTs (Version 9.0.1 Community) C++ and Visual Studios C++ (2022 Version), and I get similar results. From googling what the issue might be, I found mentions of multiple instances trying to access the same dll, but that is beyond my level of programming knowledge. I have attached the code I wrote in QT as well as in Visual Studio.
Thanks in advance.

```cpp
void CMFCApplication2Dlg::ClickStarthomingbutton()
{
    
    Piezo1.StartCtrl();
    Piezo2.StartCtrl();

    Sleep(2000);
    
    Piezo1.EnableHWChannel(0);
    Piezo2.EnableHWChannel(0);

    Sleep(2000);

    Piezo1.Identify();
    Piezo2.Identify();
    
    Sleep(2000);

    Piezo1.DisableHWChannel(0);
    Piezo2.DisableHWChannel(0);

    Sleep(2000);
    Piezo1.StopCtrl();
    Piezo2.StopCtrl();
    

    LPCTSTR Name = L"Worked fine";
    
    Caption.put__Value(Name);

}
```

This works fine, if I remove everything with Piezo2, the Label "Caption" will display "Worked fine", and the window will not close. If I run it as is, the Label will not display Worked fine, and will close.

```cpp
QAxWidget* PiezoX;
PiezoX = new QAxWidget();
PiezoX->setControl("{A9BC6065-D4F4-4A77-B42B-215A9D6DF4C6}");
PiezoX->setProperty("HWSerialNum", 91809021);


QAxWidget* PiezoY;
PiezoY = new QAxWidget();
PiezoY->setControl("{A9BC6065-D4F4-4A77-B42B-215A9D6DF4C6}");
PiezoY->setProperty("HWSerialNum", 91809022);

PiezoX -> dynamicCall("StartCtrl");
PiezoY -> dynamicCall("StartCtrl");

QThread::sleep(1);
qInfo() << "Worked fine";

PiezoX -> dynamicCall("StopCtrl");
PiezoY -> dynamicCall("StopCtrl");
```

This also never prints "Worked fine" into the console.

I did try different chanIDs for EnableHWChannel(), but they dont appear to do anything. This comes from the special architecture of the three channel units.

Comment: I guess your piezo thingy sucks and you should ask the manufacturer for a refund... or advice. This is nothing to do with ActiveX or MFC. It's everything to do with your piezo thingy.

Comment: @user253751 That could very well be the case. I talked to them, they claimed it would work in Visual Studio, which I then switched to from QT. After testing it today, it did not work. Just throwing it out there, could my Windows Version be a problem? I'm still using Windows 10, could upgrading to 11 help?

Comment: no............. your problem is entirely to do with the piezo thingy and nothing to do with Windows, QT, or ActiveX

Comment: Damn, ok, Thank you <3

Comment: `Sleep`-ing your UI thread is never a good idea. And since you're hosting ActiveX controls on that UI thread (which need an active message loop to dispatch messages) this *could* be part of the problem.

Comment: Could you provide some references for me to read up on for that? Sleep is used in these places to ensure that no two commands are sent too quickly, if I remove it sometimes I get errors from ActiveX that I am trying to interface with a controller that is not connected. If I remove them, the same error occurs anyway, so yeah.